# Asynchronous Java: How to return this without blocking?

Tags: java, asynchronous, reactive-programming, spring-webflux, project-reactor

Setup:

```
public Mono<String> getResult(Mono<Boolean> flagMono, Mono<String> resultMono) {
    return flagMono.map(flag -> {
        if (flag) return "FLAG IS TRUE, SKIP RESULT";
        return resultMono.block(); // how to do without blocking?
    });
}
```

Hopefully, what I'm trying to accomplish is clear and it's just a matter of writing it out correctly. I would like to return the string constant if `flag` is true, otherwise return the string result returned by `resultMono` in a non-blocking way.

Comment: Maybe use flatMap instead of map and return resultMono...?

Comment: If computing the result may require blocking, then I don't see how you imagine returning it without any possibility of blocking.  But you could perhaps start an asynchronous computation and return a `Future` from which the result can later be obtained when it's available.

Answer (score 2):

```
public Mono<String> getResult(Mono<Boolean> flagMono, Mono<String> resultMono) {
    return flagMono.flatMap(flag -> {
        if (flag) return Mono.just("FLAG IS TRUE, SKIP RESULT");
        return resultMono;
    });
}
```